# Proof by contradiction - help!?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, rational-numbers

I need to prove that the set of rational numbers in the closed interval 0,1 has a supremum and infimum. I know that they exist and I also know that I need to use proof by contradiction but I don't know how..

I'm really struggling with this so any help would be hugely appreciated!

thank you

Comment: Do you know what the supremum and infimum are? That’s really the first thing that you need to pin down here.

Comment: USE THE DEFINITION.

Comment: I know i'm looking for the largest lower bound and the smallest of the upper bounds which is 0.. But I don't know how to start my proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$.  If $a \in A$, then $a \in [0,1]$, so $0 \le a \le 1$.  So $A$ is bounded above and below by $0$ and $1$ respectively.  So we have that $0 \le \inf(A) $ and $ \sup(A) \le 1$.

Now if $a \in A$ and $a < 1$, then $a < \frac{1 + a}{2} < 1$, and it's easy to see that $\frac{1+a}{2} \in A$.  This shows that $\sup(A) = 1$.  Argue similarly on the infimum.

Comment: what would be the case for a half open interval i.e. ]0,1] in a set of real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Write down the definition of supremum and infimum. Not sure why you need to use a proof by contradiction, but it is relatively straightforward to show that $1$ is the supremum and $0$ is the infimum. This will hold even if you change your closed interval to an open interval.

**Use the definitions.**

Comment: @Anona anon If you're required to use a proof by contradiction just suppose that $1$ isn't the supremum and that $0$ isn't the infimum and then mimic the direct proof suggested by this answer to reach a contradiction.